# Cocoapods/Podspec exclude headers from HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Some projects I'm working on depend on set of C libraries which I want to manage with wonderful CocoaPods. Each library has private headers like ctype.h, errno.h, string.h deep in the structure. I need them to be copied to Pods/Headers, but NOT flattened in the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS as it breaks build process.

C-library has the following structure:

```
mylib/include/mylib.h
mylib/include/core/errno.h
...
```

I want all the headers to be copied to Pod Headers folder, but HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS include "mylib/include" only.

Everything I add using source_files or public_header_files goes to HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in various Pod .xconfig. If I exclude some headers, they disappear from HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS, but also not copied to Headers.

Any ideas how to solve such problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the files with the exclude_files directive.
http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#exclude_files

It works for both source files and headers.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the headers you want hidden as [`private_header_files`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#private_header_files)